# How do I get a value from an zigbee2mqtt sensor

Tags: zigbee

Do the sensors just send values whenever they feel like it and I have to be connected to `mqtt` and listening at the time in order to witness it?

Or can I request the sensor to send a value?

Can I get the last value that was seen (and its timestamp)? (I see I can set `retain: true` in `configuration.yml` -- is that all there is?)

I tried

```
#  mosquitto_pub -t 'zigbee2mqtt/Temp1/get' -m '{"state": ""}'
```

but it just causes this to appear in the log:

```
error 2022-01-26 21:50:45: No converter available for 'state' ("")
```

What does it mean?
(The sensor is a TuYa WSD500A.)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't query the state of the sensor when you want to.
You can only send the calibration commands described in https://smarthomescene.com/reviews/tuya-temperature-humidity-sensor-wsd500a/
But these commands are only for the Zigbee2MQTT module, not for the sensor.

Since this unit is battery powered - it is not listening to the coordinator to receive commands.

The sensor itself wakes up periodically and sends data periodically (I noticed an interval of 5 to 30 minutes), or, as they say, if any parameter changes significantly.

You can also initiate sending of values by pressing a button on the back of the sensor housing.

Comment: Thanks. It made me realise why my radiator valve behaves differently to a smart plug. :-)